# how to give shadow effect to div on hover

Tags: html, css

i am working in bootstrap. Kindly guide me how to give shadow-effect to a div on hover.

```css
.shadow-effects:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-md-12 bg_white shadow-effects" id="box">
    <div class="col-md-10 pd-left-right-0">
      <h4 class="box_title">One Click installation. Super easy to use</h4>
      <h5 class="text">Installation is prety easy,just click on "import demo" button and you are set. We've told you it's pretty easy</h5>
      <p class="box_bottom">DISCOVER MORE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 pd-left-right-0">
      <img src="images/cloud-computing-icon.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is not working

Comment: “not working” is not a problem statement. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Comment: thankyou... yes code is working properly now ....problem was that shadow was appearing without hover and on hover it disappears......i need shadow to appear on hover

Answer (score 0):

I just literally copy pasted your code, everything seems to be working !!, check below

```css
.shadow-effects:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg_white shadow-effects" id="box">
        <div class="col-md-10 pd-left-right-0">
            <h4 class="box_title">One Click installation. Super easy to use</h4>
            <h5 class="text">Installation is prety easy,just click on "import demo" button and you are set. We've told you it's pretty easy</h5>
            <p class="box_bottom">DISCOVER MORE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 pd-left-right-0">
            <img src="images/cloud-computing-icon.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think something else is messed up. the code u gave is perfectly fine and works. Maybe you have a duplicate id or the div is being blocked or something

Answer (score -2):

make this code

```
.shadow-effects:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

into

```
#box:hover{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
}
```

**hope it helps**

Comment: changing id to class does not make any difference in this scenario.